# How can one know how many possible abelian and non abelian group be formed from a given number of elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory

Suppose that $G=\{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$ and how many abelian and non abelian group can be formed from this $n$ element?

Attempts : I have tried consider the simple case. when n=2, there is only 1 possible which is abilean. For n=3, there are also only 1 abilean group exist. But when $n$ come to a bigger integer like $10$ or even $n$ in general, is there any way to determine the possible group can be formed from a given number of $n$

Comment: This sounds like it might relate to Sylow theory.

Comment: @Clayton I have tried to search this theorem and i found so many different theorem about this, there is even a book talks about this theorem but i am not so sure how the theorem is related. What are the most important result derived from this theorem?

Comment: I think I don't quite know what you are asking - there is (up to isomorphism) only one group with three elements, and that is abelian. The smallest nonabelian group has six elements (this is isomorphic to the symmetric group on three letters) - so are you thinking of permutation groups?

Comment: @MarkBennet i made some mistake sorry

Answer (score 3):

For abelian groups, we know that the group must be the product of cyclic groups, and this allows us to obtain a fairly explicit formula.  If $n=p_1^{a_1}\ldots p_m^{a_m}$ is the prime factorization of $n$, and if $p(a)$ is the number of partitions of $a$, then the number of abelian groups of order $n$ is

$$\prod_{i=1}^mp(a_i)$$

In general, if we try to count all groups of a specific order, this is a very difficult question, although there are results for specific $n$.  For example, if $n$ is prime, there is only one group, or if $n$ is the square of a prime there are only $2$ groups, and both are abelian.  If $n=2^k$, then the number of groups of order $k$ is roughly

$$2^{\frac{2}{27}k^3+O(k^{\frac{8}{3}})}$$

For example, there are $49487365422$ groups of order $1024$.  If $n=pq$, with $p<q$ and $p\not\mid q-1$, then there is only one group of order $n$.

So there is no explicit formula for the number of groups of order $n$, and there is not much hope of obtaining one unless we specify something about the prime factorization of $n$.  Even in that case, the problem is very difficult.

Comment: One more thing that can be said: the number of groups of order $n$ when $n$ is *squarefree* is given by $$\sum_{m\mid n}\prod_p\frac{p^{c(p)}-1}{p-1}$$ where $c(p)$ counts the prime divisors of $m$ congruent to $1$ mod $p$. This result goes [back to Holder](http://www.rose-hulman.edu/mathjournal/archives/2010/vol11-n1/paper7/v11n1-7pd.pdf).

Comment: @anon: That's a very nice result.  I wasn't aware of that.  Thanks!